# How to get all rows in Azure table Storage in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, nosql, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am trying to get a list of all entities inside an azure table.

Any idea of how I would write this query?

Comment: Are you using any language specific library e.g. .Net Storage Client library?

Comment: I am using the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage library

Answer (score 118, accepted):

To answer your question, you could do something like the following:

```
var acc = new CloudStorageAccount(
                         new StorageCredentials("account name", "account key"), true);
var tableClient = acc.CreateCloudTableClient();
var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("table name");
var entities = table.ExecuteQuery(new TableQuery<MyEntity>()).ToList();
```

However please keep in mind that table service returns a maximum of 1000 entities in a single call to it. If there're more than 1000 entities available in your table, it returns a `continuation token` which can be used to fetch next set of entities. The `ExecuteQuery` method actually handles this continuation token internally thus if you want to cancel this operation for any reason, you can't do that.

A better approach would be to use `ExecuteQuerySegmented` method and have your application deal with the token. Here's the sample code to do so:

```
var acc = new CloudStorageAccount(
                         new StorageCredentials("account name", "account key"), true);
var tableClient = acc.CreateCloudTableClient();
var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("table name");
TableContinuationToken token = null;
var entities = new List<MyEntity>();
do
{
    var queryResult = table.ExecuteQuerySegmented(new TableQuery<MyEntity>(), token);
    entities.AddRange(queryResult.Results);
    token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
} while (token != null);
```

Comment: I was only able to get PartitionKey and RowKey from this. In order to get all properties, you must add: "var entities = table.ExecuteQuery(new TableQuery<MyModel>()).ToList();" (add <MyModel>). This was not obvious to me :)

Comment: In this case MyEntity is our own class? so what are the getter or setter are going to be for it?

Comment: Bit confused as to the use of 'false' on the first lines of both sample codes - to be clear, you're actively disabling HTTPS on the connection, right? Why would that be beneficial to peg-back to HTTP?

Comment: @BrettRigby...You're correct. It's a bad idea to let the traffic go over `http`. I have fixed the code. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't need all rows every time, it's more efficient to retrieve items on demand (lazily) by making use of `yield`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll<T>(string tableName) where T : class
{
    var table = this.GetCloudTable(tableName);
    TableContinuationToken token = null;
    do
    {
        var q = new TableQuery<T>();
        var queryResult = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(q, token);
        foreach (var item in queryResult.Results)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
        token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
    } while (token != null);
}
```

With this approach, you can get all rows, but if you're looping through the results of `GetAll()` and find what you're looking for, you can just `break` the loop, and the `GetAll()` method would stop without retrieving the next rows from the table.

Answer (score 10):

With the newer Azure.Data.Tables SDK this is now much shorter, especially when using the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) nuget package. With that you can simplay write:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Returns all rows in the table
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Implementation of ITableEntity</typeparam>
/// <param name="tableClient">The authenticated TableClient</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static async Task<List<T>> GetAllEntitiesAsync<T>(this TableClient tableClient) where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
{
    return await tableClient.QueryAsync<T>(maxPerPage: 1000).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Note: by requesting 1000 rows at once (max) the total amount of requests can be drastically reduced.

[Source](https://github.com/ThomasPe/Azure.Data.Tables-Extensions/blob/main/src/Medienstudio.Azure.Data.Tables.Extensions/Extensions.cs#L66)

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I am new to Azure Functions and Azure Table Storage. I got confused with CloudTable, ClientTable, different libraries, etc. This helped me greatly!