# How to increase the retrive count in "ExecuteQuerySegmented" in Azure Storage table Query

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I want to retrive the record from azure storage table with top 1000 records. This table has million of records.

Herer is my code, Its not working.

```
CloudStorageAccount dataFETCH_storageAccount =  CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("PROD_StorageConnectionString"));
CloudTableClient dataFETCH_storageTableClient = dataFETCH_storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
dataFETCH_tbl = dataFETCH_storageTableClient.GetTableReference("TableName");
TableQuery tableQuery = new TableQuery().Take(1000);
var queryResult = tcpMasterStorageTable_Org.ExecuteQuerySegmented(tableQuery, token);
```

Anyone help me on this problem?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I am not getting error. By default, its giving me only 72 records.

Comment: I think this should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940246/how-to-query-all-rows-in-windows-azure-table-storage/23940749#23940749