# Azure C# v2 Function: TableContinuationToken does not contain a definition for ContinuationToken

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to read the first ten rows of an Azure Table Storage using Azure v2 C# Function + .NET Core SDK 3.1. However, I get the following error in this line of code (`token = token.ContinuationToken;`):

> 'TableContinuationToken' does not contain a definition for
> 'ContinuationToken'

However, this doesn't make much sense considering that in this answer ([How to get all rows in Azure table Storage in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940246/how-to-get-all-rows-in-azure-table-storage-in-c)), the writer of that answer retrieved the `ContinuationToken` attribute from a `TableContinuationToken` object. Below is my code:

```
StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);

// Retrieve the role assignments table
CloudTableClient client = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference("OneAuthZRoleAssignments");

// Test out retrieving a small portion from the role assignments table (10 rows)
var tablePortion = new List<RoleAssignment>();
TableContinuationToken token = null;
var rowCount = 0;
do
{
    var queryResult = table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery<RoleAssignment>(), token);
    tablePortion.AddRange(queryResult.Result);
    token = token.ContinuationToken;
    rowCount++;
} while (rowCount < 10);

// Print out the contents of the table
foreach (RoleAssignment role in tablePortion)
{
    Console.WriteLine(role.Timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the following line:

```
token = token.ContinuationToken;
```

to

```
token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
```

**UPDATE**

Please try the following code:

```
do
{
    var queryResult = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(new TableQuery<RoleAssignment>(), token);
    tablePortion.AddRange(queryResult.Result);
    token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
    rowCount++;
} while (rowCount < 10);
```

Essentially you're not `awaiting` an `async` operation.

Comment: I also get this error unfortunately: Task<TableQuerySegment<RoleAssignment>> does not contain a definition for ContinuationToken

Comment: Is it possible I am missing an import? Seems like it could be the case but I don't know what it is...

Comment: What version of Storage SDK you're using?

Comment: Never mind...you're missing `await` :). I have updated my answer. Please try that.